# Add a new transport driver to Laravel's Mailer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to add a new transport driver to Laravel's mail package so that I can send e-mails through an external service (Mailjet) that isn't supported by default.

Writing the transport driver won't be a problem, but I can't find a way to hook in and add a new one so I can continue to use Laravel's mailer as normal. I can't find any documentation on extending the Mailer.

The only way I can come up with would be to replace where Laravel's `MailServiceProvider` is being referenced in `config/app.php` with my own service provider, which I could then use to register my own `TransportManager` and my own transport driver.

Is there a better way to add another transport driver?

Comment: Yes, you have to create your own `Mailer` class. Preferably, your class should implement [Mailer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/Mailer.php) and [MailQueue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/MailQueue.php) interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That does seem a bit over the top just to be able to add my own driver for another service. I would rather hook into as much of Laravel's functionality as possible. See my answer below for how I've managed to implement it so far.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I've managed to get it working in the way I suggested in my question (By writing my own `ServiceProvider` and `TransportManager` to allow me to provider a driver). This is what I've done for anyone that might come across this:

**config/app.php** - Replace Laravel's `MailServiceProvider` with my own

```
// ...
'providers' => [
    // ...

    // Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    App\MyMailer\MailServiceProvider::class,

    // ...
```

**app/MyMailer/MailServiceProvider.php** - Create a service provider that extends Laravel's `MailServiceProvider` and override the `registerSwiftTransport()` method

```
<?php

namespace App\MyMailer;

class MailServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider
{
    public function registerSwiftTransport()
    {
        $this->app['swift.transport'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {
            // Note: This is my own implementation of transport manager as shown below
            return new TransportManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

**app/MyMailer/TransportManager.php** - Add a `createMailjetDriver` method which makes my `MailjetTransport` driver available to Laravel's Mailer

```
<?php

namespace App\MyMailer;

use App\MyMailer\Transport\MailjetTransport;

class TransportManager extends \Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager
{
    protected function createMailjetDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']->get('services.mailjet', []);

        return new MailjetTransport(
            $this->getHttpClient($config),
            $config['api_key'],
            $config['secret_key']
        );
    }
}
```

**app/MyMailer/Transport/MailjetTransport.php** - My own Transport driver that sends e-mails through Mailjet.

*Updated to contain my implementation of the Mailjet transport driver. Using [the Mailjet guide for sending a basic e-mail through their API](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?shell#sending-a-basic-email) as a base*.

```
<?php

namespace App\MyMailer\Transport;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport;
use Swift_Mime_Message;

class MailjetTransport extends Transport
{
    /**
     * Guzzle HTTP client.
     *
     * @var ClientInterface
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * The Mailjet "API key" which can be found at https://app.mailjet.com/transactional
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $apiKey;

    /**
     * The Mailjet "Secret key" which can be found at https://app.mailjet.com/transactional
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $secretKey;

    /**
     * The Mailjet end point we're using to send the message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $endPoint = 'https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send';

    /**
     * Create a new Mailjet transport instance.
     *
     * @param  \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface $client
     * @param $apiKey
     * @param $secretKey
     */
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, $apiKey, $secretKey)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
    }

    /**
     * Send the given Message.
     *
     * Recipient/sender data will be retrieved from the Message API.
     * The return value is the number of recipients who were accepted for delivery.
     *
     * @param Swift_Mime_Message $message
     * @param string[] $failedRecipients An array of failures by-reference
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        $this->beforeSendPerformed($message);

        $payload = [
            'header' => ['Content-Type', 'application/json'],
            'auth' => [$this->apiKey, $this->secretKey],
            'json' => []
        ];

        $this->addFrom($message, $payload);
        $this->addSubject($message, $payload);
        $this->addContent($message, $payload);
        $this->addRecipients($message, $payload);

        return $this->client->post($this->endPoint, $payload);
    }

    /**
     * Add the from email and from name (If provided) to the payload.
     *
     * @param Swift_Mime_Message $message
     * @param array $payload
     */
    protected function addFrom(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$payload)
    {
        $from = $message->getFrom();

        $fromAddress = key($from);
        if ($fromAddress) {
            $payload['json']['FromEmail'] = $fromAddress;

            $fromName = $from[$fromAddress] ?: null;
            if ($fromName) {
                $payload['json']['FromName'] = $fromName;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the subject of the email (If provided) to the payload.
     *
     * @param Swift_Mime_Message $message
     * @param array $payload
     */
    protected function addSubject(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$payload)
    {
        $subject = $message->getSubject();
        if ($subject) {
            $payload['json']['Subject'] = $subject;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the content/body to the payload based upon the content type provided in the message object. In the unlikely
     * event that a content type isn't provided, we can guess it based on the existence of HTML tags in the body.
     *
     * @param Swift_Mime_Message $message
     * @param array $payload
     */
    protected function addContent(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$payload)
    {
        $contentType = $message->getContentType();
        $body = $message->getBody();

        if (!in_array($contentType, ['text/html', 'text/plain'])) {
            $contentType = strip_tags($body) != $body ? 'text/html' : 'text/plain';
        }

        $payload['json'][$contentType == 'text/html' ? 'Html-part' : 'Text-part'] = $message->getBody();
    }

    /**
     * Add to, cc and bcc recipients to the payload.
     *
     * @param Swift_Mime_Message $message
     * @param array $payload
     */
    protected function addRecipients(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$payload)
    {
        foreach (['To', 'Cc', 'Bcc'] as $field) {
            $formatted = [];
            $method = 'get' . $field;
            $contacts = (array) $message->$method();
            foreach ($contacts as $address => $display) {
                $formatted[] = $display ? $display . " <$address>" : $address;
            }

            if (count($formatted) > 0) {
                $payload['json'][$field] = implode(', ', $formatted);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `.env` file I have:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailjet
```

..which allows me to use Laravel's mailer package (Through the Facade or dependency injection) as normal:

```
\Mail::send('view', [], function($message) {
    $message->to('me@domain.com');
    $message->subject('Test');
});
```

Comment: Did you got it working at the end? Using the Mailjet API maybe? 
`MailjetTransport::send()`

Comment: I haven't finished implementing it yet but I have previously implemented the Mailjet API, so I'm pretty confident it will work when I'm done. I'll be using Guzzle to hit their `send` end point.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll try that too.

Comment: No problem. I can possibly update my answer later when I'm done. Take a look at the `MailgunTransport` or `MandrillTransport` that come with Laravel, they'll give you a good idea of what you need to do.

Comment: That would be great, I have already used Guzzle, but any help could be good for everyone here anyway :)

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby I've updated my answer to include my current implementation. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Excellent, thank you again! Just to be sure, did you have to do this because of authentication, or is it possible to use the SMTP relay directly?

Comment: No problem. I just preferred to do it this way, I think you can do it either way.  Their documentation is really good and should help you implement it another way if you prefer. The API key and secret key are your SMTP credentials too.

Comment: Good to know, thanks :) If I find something useful by my side, I'll let you know. I think the mailing system slightly change with Laravel 5.3 (yet unstable), with the new concept of Notifications too.

Comment: Great, thanks. Yeah that was my worry too, but it looks currently like this will still work. It seems that they've just added support for the new `Mailable` objects into their existing Mail package

Comment: can you update answer for laravel 6 please? @Jonathon

Comment: I am facing weird thing, i have configured mailjet as per documentation & checked by sending mail, but its not forwarding i can see mail request seems fine by its status code by 200. Not sure what's the issue ? Any thoughts ?